# how to make this `R` happy in android project?

Tags: android

Really newbie to Android project, but just want to run a demo project from [here](https://pay.weixin.qq.com/wiki/doc/api/download/SDKSample_Android_v3_pay.zip)

After import to the new Gradle style, found that some code like `builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);` `R` can't find the dependency,

And I checked other project's which `R` is happy, but did not find any dependency imported explicitly.

And the magic `Alt+Enter` is not working this time either :-(

This may be a silly question, but please give some guidance.

[image]

Comment: Try to clean project.

Comment: clean the project and rebuild it. This gonna solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and Rebuild your Project.

It will rebuild your R file for your specific project and don't import R from Any other package only import from "'your.package.name'.R".

Answer (score 1):

Check Which R file you have imported in this class , you should import R file of your package.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:-

1) Check if you have imported 'R' or not, if not import it by clicking "Alt+Enter" in windows/linux.

2) Clean & rebuild your project and then try to run it.

I think this will definitely solve your problem.